# Brownian dynamics simulation

Tags: random, simulation

is there any way to improve computational speed of the following Brownian dynamics simulation of a trapped particle in the Markovian case ? I time-discretized the equation of motion and then use a simple `Table` to compute one x-value after the other.

Here is my code:

```
(*Initial condition*)
x[0] = 0.;
(*Constants*)
kB = 1.;
T = 1.;
gm = 1.;
kappa = 1.;
(*Time step*)
dt = 10.^-2;
(*Number of steps*)
Ntot = 10.^5;
(*Compute a single trajectory*)
Timing[
 list = Table[{n*dt, 
     x[n] = x[n - 1] - (kappa/gm)*x[n - 1]*
        dt + (1./gm) Sqrt[2. gm*kB*T]*Sqrt[dt]*
        RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0., 1.]]}, {n, 
     Range[1, Ntot]}];]
(*Plotting the trajectory*)
ListPlot[list, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Is there a faster way to do this (regarding the Mathematica synthax/programming style)? For a high number of steps `Ntot` this takes a very long time unfortunately. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You might also try [ItoProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItoProcess.html?q=ItoProcess) and similar.

Answer (score 11):

Things we can improve with small changes:

1. You are recomputing a bunch of constants at each iteration, like `(1./gm)`, `Sqrt[2. gm*kB*T]`. Compute them once.
2. It is much more efficient to compute all the random numbers in one go, before the iteration starts.
3. The ideomatic way to build up lists based on previous list elements in *Mathematica* is `FoldList`, so let's try to use that.
4. This one is not about speed but style: we don't want to make capitalized variable names in *Mathematica*, as they might conflict with built-in symbols, and also they make the use of auto-completion more cumbersome.

Here is the modified code:

```
(*Constants*)
kB = 1.;
t = 1.;
gm = 1.;
kappa = 1.;
(*Time step*)
dt = 10.^-2;
(*Number of steps*)
nTot = 10.^5;

factor1 = 1 - (kappa/gm)*dt;
scaledRandomNumbers = (1./gm) Sqrt[2. gm*kB*t]*Sqrt[dt] * RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., 1.], nTot];

AbsoluteTiming[
  list = Rest @ FoldList[{#2*dt, #1[[2]]*factor1 + scaledRandomNumbers[[#2]]}&, {0, 0.}, Range[nTot]];
]
```

### Multiple trajectories

Only a small modification is needed:

```
nTraj = 5;
scaledRandomNumbers = (1./gm) Sqrt[2. gm*kB*t]*Sqrt[dt]*
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., 1.], {nTot, nTraj}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 list = Rest@
    FoldList[{#2*dt, #1[[2]]*factor1 + 
        scaledRandomNumbers[[#2]]} &, {0, ConstantArray[0., nTraj]}, 
     Range[nTot]];]
```

Now `list[[m]]` will look like

```
{m*dt, {x[1][m], x[2][m], ..., x[nTraj][m]}}
```

To plot e.g. trajectory nr. 3 we can do

```
ListPlot[
  Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2, 3]]}]
,Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help.  I do not just yet understand the functionality of `FoldList` because I have never used it before. I hope the documentation will be helpful here. I recognized that if you at another "." to the first "0" in the last line it is even faster.

Comment: A look into the documentation was helpful. This improves the speed already a lot thank you. If you have any further advice to improve it, don't hesitate and let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I now would like to compute several trajectories lets say `nTraj=10^2`. I use `ParallelTable` to store the random numbers in `scaledRandomNumbers[m]`. Then I introduce another table where I define `list[m]` where m displays the number of trajectorie. However, these tables are slowing it down again. Is there any smarter way how to generalize the code for several trajectories?

Comment: See my edit. Looks like it's still pretty fast even for `nTraj = 100`.

Comment: Note: I _think_ the distribution of the random numbers is still correct in the multi-trajectory case, but I'm not an expert on that. Doing `Transpose@Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., 1.], nTot], {nTraj}]` should be safe on that account though.

Comment: Thanks again. I see one should avoid `Table` whenever possible. However, to me it was more intuitive to index my lists for the random numbers and for the trajectories and simply use loops in order to compute them. In this way, one severely slows down the computation though. Is there any reason for this? See my code in another answer.

Comment: Search this site for "avoid loops", "why not For" or similar, you will find many reasons why.

Comment: Ok, I will do this. I posted my first try code nevertheless. It is strange because if I plug in the values in `list[k]` by hand it is fast. But as soon as I use the table command it is way slower...

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but is there a way to parallelize this computation efficiently as I tried above? I can make use of >10 local kernels, so compution on a single core is rather inefficient and later on I want to look at more complex examples. Thank you.

Comment: On my computer this problem simply does not parallelize well, probably because the overhead associated with moving the relatively large amounts of data between kernels is large compared to the time needed per data point, that we have made very low by using vectorized operations. In general my experience is that vectorization is much more important for speed than parallelization in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Is there a way to include memory and stick to the built-in function `FoldList`? By including memory the discretized equation of motion does not only depend on the x-value of the previous time step, but also on x-values further in the past. In the discretized equation of motion a sum will appear, and I am not sure whether I can implement this with `FoldList`. If you have any suggestions feel free to answer again. I will think about this for a while. Though, if `FoldList` doesn't apply anymore, I need to reconstruct my code.

Comment: This should indeed be possible, but then you would have to make the function (the first argument in `FoldList`) take as input not only the prev. value but a `List` of all previus values, and it must return this list with the new value appended.

Comment: I have problems how to do all this within the function `FoldList` itself. I mean I need to define or rather create that `List` within each contraction of `FoldList` in order to use it for the next contraction (as first argument) of the function. Of course I know how to create a list with all the values of `FoldList` but I do not know how to do it in each "cycle" of `FoldList`.  Helps much appreciated again.

Comment: Ok, solved it now with `Append`. I know that one should usually stick to `Reap` and `Sow`, but I have no idea how to use it when I do not build the data all at once but successively.